# Button is not responding from the first click

Tags: multithreading, vaadin

I have a problem with a button in that it doesn't work on the first click. I have to click twice and it then gives double results:

```
Button button = new Button("Click Me");
button.addClickListener(
    new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    DateChooser dateChooser = new DateChooser(new com.kopiright.xkopi.lib.type.Date(2013, 12, 9));
                    System.out.println(dateChooser.selectDate(com.kopiright.xkopi.lib.type.Date.now()).toString());
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
);
```

DateChooser extends com.vaadin.ui.Panel class.

Comment: wow but i never changed the setImmediate, Thank you nexus

Answer (score 4):

Vaadin Button is always immediate so that's not the problem here.

The problem is that you are starting an external thread, which updates the UI, and to see  changes made to the UI by an external thread, you should use pollig or pushing. In this case the second button click polls the changes to the browser. But in this case you can just remove the thread:

```
button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        DateChooser dateChooser = new DateChooser(new com.kopiright.xkopi.lib.type.Date(2013, 12, 9));
        System.out.println(dateChooser.selectDate(com.kopiright.xkopi.lib.type.Date.now()).toString());       
    }
});
```

And when an external thread is used to update Vaadin components, the code must be synchronized correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you create a new thread for this?

Please be aware that modifying the GUI from a thread mus be synchronized.

Look in the book of vaadin for this:

11.16.3. Accessing UI from Another Thread

https://vaadin.com/de/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.push.html

André

Comment: @AmiraGL What's the reason for this requirement. I think you are misunderstanding on how to program with Vaadin. Did you try to remove the thread?